# Block input if it's not the letter "A"

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can I do that if the user is not typing `A`, then there will not be any output? I want to do this in a `EditText`.

Code:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 
                    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
                            if (!Character.toString(source.charAt(i)).equals("a")) { 
                                    return ""; 
                            } 
                    } 
                    return null; 
            } 
        };
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I tried something with InputFilter but it doesn't work..

Comment: @BartWesselink without typing how an EditText have characters in it

Comment: But how can you block that when it's not a?

Comment: @BartWesselink now I understand you, post your code

Comment: I will put it in the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it the way that you are attempting to, with an input filter, but I would recommend that you do it in XML instead, by giving your edittext the attribute `android:digits="Aa"`. That should solve your problem.

If you need to use an input filter try this (it is untested and may not work an better than yours)

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 
                    String chars = "";
                    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
                            if (Character.toString(source.charAt(i)).equals("a")) { 
                                    chars = chars + source.charAt(i);
                            } else {
                                //don't add anything to the char sequence
                            }
                    } 
                    return chars; 
            } 
        };
```

Comment: A was for example, it's always an other letter. Sorry

Comment: @BartWesselink - try the code that I added, it might work

Comment: Huh, it doesn't work.. (In the emulator I use the keyboard of my laptop)

Comment: @BartWesselink - I updated the code, what didn't work?

Comment: No. I don't see why it isn't working...

Comment: Ah now I see why it isn't working, it was my mistake! I put the filter on the textview..